# How to output random letters in java and get the total, high score and lowest score?

Tags: java

Basically, I'm trying to output random uppercase letters and the loops go on forever what am I doing wrong?

I've tried other methods using java.util.Scanner for my input dialog but other than that I can't see what's wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlotMachine {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String HOWN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter how many times you are going to play");
        int HOW = Integer.parseInt (HOWN);
        double counter = 0;
        System.out.println("You chose to play " + HOW + " times");
        for (int i = 0; i<HOW; i++) {
            for (int b = 0; b<3; i++) {
                double result = Math.random();
                result = Math.round (result );
                result = result * ((90 - 65)+1) - 65;                         
                char resultF = (char)result;
                counter = counter + result;
                System.out.println ("");
                System.out.println("you got: " + resultF + " which is " +     result + "in ASCII code");
                System.out.println("your total is: " + counter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Also: please format / indent all of your code, not just section. That preview window exists for a reason!

Comment: You never change b so the loop condition is always met so the loop continues over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done

```
for (int b = 0; b<3; i++)
```

instead of the correct

```
 for (int b = 0; b<3; b++)
```

This should help your loop terminate.